# How to change image color through the URL after come back in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am doing one task that if have hit URL in `onCreate` after that I am going to store all URL in hash map base of object in on Click I am accessing particular object and its working fine. But after state if am press back button and come back again in fragment the URL stats if of state only how any suggestion?
My JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1404,
        "cameraId": 1184,
        "onUrl": "",
        "offUrl": "",
        "statusUrl": "",
        "type": "Strobe",
        "statusOnMessage": "P1 = on",
        "statusOffMessage": "P1 = off",
        "onSuccessMessage": "P1 = on",
        "offSuccessMessage": "P1 = off"
    },
    {
        "id": 1405,
        "cameraId": 1184,
        "onUrl": "",
        "offUrl": "",
        "statusUrl": "",
        "type": "Light",
        "statusOnMessage": "P2 = on",
        "statusOffMessage": "P2 = off",
        "onSuccessMessage": "P2 = on",
        "offSuccessMessage": "P2 = off"
    }
]
```

**after accessing this URL i am store all the data in hash map and access the url in on click event but after come back again the same fragment this is go back in previews state only  **
code:

```
private void getActionURl() {
    final String potentialId = SitesUtil.getInstance().getSelectedPotentialId();

    String urlOne = UrlUtility.getActionUrl(potentialId, cameraId);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlOne, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            try {
                ActionButton[] actionButton = gson.fromJson(response, ActionButton[].class);
                for (ActionButton actionButton1 : actionButton) {
                    actionButtonMap.put(actionButton1.getType(), actionButton1);


                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.imageButton:


        /*  final  ActionButton*/
            btnConfig = actionButtonMap.get("Strobe");
            if (btnConfig == null) {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sensor Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

        {
            if (isStrobe) ----> its local Boolean value{
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, btnConfig.getOnUrl(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {


                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), btnConfig.getOnSuccessMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            isStrobe = false;

                            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_alarm);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            } else {
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, btnConfig.getOffUrl(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), btnConfig.getOffSuccessMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_alarm_second);
                        isStrobe = true;
                        Utils.saveToSharedPreferenceBoolean("isStrobe", isStrobe);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }

        }
        break;
        case R.id.imageButton2:
            final ActionButton btnConfigOne = actionButtonMap.get("Light");
            if (btnConfigOne == null) {
                /*imageButtonOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sensor Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }


            if (isLight) {

                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, btnConfigOne.getOnUrl(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), btnConfigOne.getOnSuccessMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        isLight = false;

                        imageButtonOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_light_bulb);
                        Utils.saveToSharedPreferenceBoolean("isLight", isLight);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            } else {
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, btnConfigOne.getOffUrl(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), btnConfigOne.getOffSuccessMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        isLight = true;
                        imageButtonOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bulb_second);
                        //Utils.saveToSharedPreferenceBoolean("isLight", isLight);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }

            break;
        case R.id.imageButton3:
            final ActionButton btnConfigMotion = actionButtonMap.get("Motion");
            if (btnConfigMotion == null) {
                /*imageButtonTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sensor Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (isMotion) {
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, btnConfigMotion.getOnUrl(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), btnConfigMotion.getOnSuccessMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        isMotion = false;
                        imageButtonTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_motion_sensor);


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            } else {
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, btnConfigMotion.getOffUrl(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), btnConfigMotion.getOffSuccessMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        isMotion = true;
                        imageButtonTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_motion_sensor_seocond);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want i am accessing OnURL from hash map and after close the fragment and come it should be on State only but its going every time in offstage even the strobe state is on.

Comment: any suggestion on that?